# j2v8: creating new instance of binded object

Tags: javascript, java, android, j2v8, liquidcore

Our teams is currently under consideration of which JavaScript Engine Bridge to use. We are choosing between [LiquidCore](https://github.com/LiquidPlayer/LiquidCore) and [J2V8](https://github.com/eclipsesource/J2V8). 
My question is concerning j2v8. Supposedly, I have to create several instances of some java class in JavaScript, how can one achieve this in `j2v8` using standard instantiation annotation (new ClassName())? In liquidcore you can bind some class, that extends **JSFuction**, with super constructor:

```
JSFunction(JSContext ctx, final String methodName, final Class<?extends JSObject> instanceClass)
```

and register property with desired class name like this:

```
jsBaseContext.getJsContext().property("WebSocket", this);
```

and then on calling:

```
var x = new WebSocket();
```

java method *methodName* will fire, where we'll get new *instanceClass* as **JSValue** object as parameter, already binded and ready to use in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one is going to discuss this topic, i'll answer myself.
This feature is not currently considered to be added in official J2V8 release, however there is a branch on [Mizumi's](https://github.com/Mizumi) [pull request](https://github.com/eclipsesource/J2V8/pull/201). So, have a look, if you've faced similar issues.